# hql birthday query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I must query birthday users with hql.

I ve tried something like below but build failed.

Any suggestions?

```
@NamedQuery(name="USer.findTodayBorners",query="from User k where k.birthDate.month=?1 and k.birthDate.day=?2)
```

Comment: What error it gives, can post it

Comment: Did you try it as a Java one-liner, or is it part of a real Hibernate project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, this is the query:

```
@NamedQuery(name="USer.findTodayBorners",query="from User k where month(k.birthDate)=month(current_date()) and day(k.birthDate)=day(current_date()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
where k.birthDate between :start and :end
```

where :start is set to a Date with the specific date and time 0:00 and :end set to 23:59

Comment: Thanks for answer, but with that query i only get new born babies :)